# how to make animation transition android

Tags: android, layout

how can i do Transition animation android like this or how can i find it ??????
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vfq_erIPCUY)
and is there is there animation in eclipse I try this i have no success

```
   Intent janken=new Intent(Main2.this,Janken.class);  
    janken.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(janken);
```

and this too

```
public void overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim) {
    super.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have few example on [this page](http://1gravity.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55%3atransition-between-activities&catid=37%3aandroid&Itemid=59).
Your mistake comes from your overPendingTransition :
You've to define your transition in ressources and then use them :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_to_enter, R.anim.anim_to_exit);
```

And [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html), is how the animations work.

But it doesn't exist any library of transition, you can maybe find few on Internet but it won't be the ones you're looking for (which are the Windows Movie Maker transitions). I don't think that the xml of Google allowed you to do these transitions, you've to be more simple !

Hope it helps !